# xquery filename extensions

Tags: xml, xquery, filenames

I just started to learn XQuery and could not figure out why there are so many filename extensions. I encountered the following filename extensions:

**.xq, .xql, .xqm, .xqy, and .xquery.**

What are their differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filename extensions for XQuery have never been formalized by the W3C XML Query Working Group. As a result, every XQuery processor and IDE comes with different recommendations.

In BaseX, `xq` is the most widely used and preferred file suffix for [main modules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#dt-main-module). The file suffix `xqm` is recommended for [library modules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#dt-library-module). All other suffixes that you have listed are accepted as well, though (see [XQuery Extensions: Suffixes](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Extensions#Suffixes) for more details).